# Azure Swap does not work after applying Content Security Policy

Tags: azure, swap, content-security-policy

I have just applied a Content Security Policy to my Azure Web App in my development environment and it is working fine.

I can also upload it to my staging site on Azure and it runs fine there and the policy is correctly applied and then enforced by my browser.  However, when I do a swap, I get the following error:

> Cannot swap slots for site 'MySite' because the worker process in
>   'staging' slot aborted the warmup request. This may happen if site has
>   IP Restriction or URL rewrite rules that block HTTP requests.

Here is the policy that I am applying (as defined in my **web.config**)

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy"
     value="default-src     'none';
            script-src      'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
            style-src       'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';
            img-src         'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;
            connect-src     'self' https:;       
            font-src        'self' https:;
            object-src      'none';
            media-src       'self';
            child-src       'self';
            form-action     'self';
            frame-ancestors 'none'"/>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure doesn't like the carriage returns in the Content-Security-Policy value in the web.config.

If you examine the **web.config** using the **App Service Editor** (that is available through the Azure Portal) then you will see the carriage returns have been encoded and turned into

> &#xD;&#xA;

Creating the following invalid CSP which is why the swap is breaking:

> default-src 'none';&#xD;&#xA; script-src 'self' https:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';&#xD;&#xA; style-src  'self' https:
>   'unsafe-inline';&#xD;&#xA; img-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'
>   data: blob:;&#xD;&#xA; connect-src 'self' https:; &#xD;&#xA;
>   font-src 'self' https:;&#xD;&#xA; object-src 'none';&#xD;&#xA;
>   media-src 'self';&#xD;&#xA; child-src 'self';&#xD;&#xA;
>   form-action 'self';&#xD;&#xA; 
>  frame-ancestors 'none'

In short, we need to enter our CSPs all on one line which reduces the readability but is required for Azure to swap.